# how do i make pppoe use less cpu ?

Tags: cpu-usage, pppoe, high-cpu-usage

The new ISP i switched to uses pppoe.
So on my old linux (centos 6) router i decited to install a pppoe client and configure as necessary.
I say old because it's a pentium III 850 mhz with 128 MB ram used mostly for routing packets. 
It has 2 dedicated 10/100Mbit intel pci nics and it did a perfect job so far.
The problem now is that pppoe uses too much cpu even before it hits the theoretical 50% of my 100Mbit isp link, so when my lan download hits 5Mbytes/s, router's cpu usage is 100%.
Mostly used by /usr/sbin/pppoe

a ps aux gives the following

> /usr/sbin/pppoe -p /var/run/pppoe-adsl.pid.pppoe -I eth1 -T 80 -U -m
>   1412

pppd runs as follows

> /usr/sbin/pppd pty /usr/sbin/pppoe -p /var/run/pppoe-adsl.pid.pppoe -I
>   eth1 -T 80 -U  -m 1412    ipparam ppp0 linkname ppp0 noipdefault
>   noauth default-asyncmap defaultroute hide-password nodetach mtu 1492
>   mru 1492 noaccomp nodeflate nopcomp novj novjccomp user 
>   lcp-echo-interval 20 lcp-echo-failure 3

How can i get close to line speed via pppoe in this setup ?

Is there a patch or anything or are there other implementations that are faster ?
I've seen something similar to this but it was freebsd related and i'd rather keep centos for now.

Thank you :)